# DirectX 11 Adding Object to Terrain - Rastertek Tutorial

Tags: visual-c++, directx, directx-11

I've been working my way through the Rastertek DX11 Terrain Tutorials getting to "Tutorial 6: Height Based Movement" Ive read through it and created, complied etc and the tutorial itself is working fine.

At the end of each tutorial it suggests what to do next and I'm stuck when it suggests to

"Place an object that randomly moves around the terrain adjusting its height based on information from the quad tree." I dont have an idea of how to do this properly.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I would go about doing this? Either a link to a tutorial that explains how to add items as well as a terrain (which I couldn't find on the site) or just pointing me in the right direction! You might have to take a peek at the code there (found here: http://rastertek.com/tertut06.zip). Right now, the closest Ive gotten to is being able to render a 3D image from a file, but when I do that it makes the terain dissapear. So I'm clearly barking up the wrong tree. I've had a google around but that's been to no avail.

Any suggestions would be great as I'm still very new to all this.